# Creating a Form Label Element

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

How to create form label element in laravel.

I want to convert below html

```
<label class="control-label">Status <span class="required">*</span></label>
```

I used

```
{!! Form::label('status', 'Status <span class="required">*</span>', array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}
```

But the output is

```
Status <span class="required">*</span>
```

The question is how to render HTML in it, Or is there a way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't - Laravel Collective's `Form::label` function [runs it through `htmlspecialchars`](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/5a8f1380a0d5ef21cdef37e775d86566307f8358/src/FormBuilder.php#L223).

That said, `Form::label` is just generating HTML. You're fine using raw HTML for this - just add a `for="status"` to link it up to its form field.

```
<label class="control-label" for="status">Status <span class="required">*</span></label>
```

You could, I suppose, run the generated label through `htmlspecialchars_decode`, but I think that's uglier and confusing for someone else reading your code.

```
{!! htmlspecialchars_decode(Form::label('status', 'Status <span class="required">*</span>', array('class' => 'control-label'))) !!}
```